# AWS CodePipeline environment variables not passed to Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

In my CodeBuild step I have an environment variable called VUE_APP_BACKEND defined as a URL. I confirmed that this part is OK by adding `echo $VUE_APP_BACKEND` to my buildspec.yml.

That one will output

```
[Container] 2020/11/26 13:22:25 Running command echo $VUE_APP_BACKEND
https://my-url-here
```

However when I try to forward this argument into the docker build it is lost. Am I doing it incorrectly?

I have a Dockerfile that looks like this. The echo part outputs nothing.

```
#build stage
FROM node:12.18.2-alpine3.10 as build-stage

ARG VUE_APP_BACKEND
ENV VUE_APP_BACKEND $VUE_APP_BACKEND
RUN echo $VUE_APP_BACKEND

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

# Bundle app source
COPY package*.json ./
COPY .npmrc ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .
RUN npm run build

#production stage
FROM nginx:1.14.1-alpine as production-stage

COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist/spa /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

Comment: Could it be that `RUN` does not respect `ENV` variables? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Comment: @luk2302 Not sure, but the npm run build is not working out well, as the application is missing the environment variables.

Comment: I believe _VUE_APP_BACKEND_ (env) is taking its value from _VUE_APP_BACKEND_ (arg), unless you pass a value using --arg during build time that value will always be empty.

Comment: @OscarNevarez Ahh, I see. Is there a trick to pass environment variables from host environment, or do I have to pass -arg every time? Annoying to maintain a list of environment variables multiple different places. (.env.example, package.json, Dockerfile etc.)

Comment: Well, most of the time args are used to condition the _flavor_ of the image during build time meanwhile envs are used to provide context execution. Regarding envs management, you can have an .env file and pass it to the docker _run_ command using the --env-file argument. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/